# Are there any way to get mirror modifier for camera with geometry node now that everything node have started to land?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, mirror, mirror-modifier

I wish to generate synthetic data for analysis of structure from motion scene reconstruction for a rig of cameras that look like that:

[image: cameras that should be mirrored]

As you can see, my two cameras should act like if there were a mirror modifier that uses the rig as origin, but as it's impossible to put modifier on cameras.

I have tried with constraints, but it's hard to get real mirror, it usually gimball lock as it doesn't work like I wish in local space, I don't think using drivers would be any better in this regard (I don't master quaternions algorithm for mirror)

I wanted to know if it was possible using geometry node, I've seen that everything node had started to land on recent versions of blender, I still only see geometry node and no object-node as of now, I wonder if such thing is yet possible without python scripting or not?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that a deep mirror, with the image reflected,  or a shallow mirror, location and orientation only?

Comment: I don't know what should a deep-mirror be, but I wish to act like the mirror modifier does for objects (copy rotation inverted)

Comment: OK, you still want the image in the mirrored camera to be the right way round. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I want it to work like that : https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2twjlrq54bmaaqz3q1agn/2023-11-07-21-18-29.mp4?rlkey=slc30p3hpmfgk8tqsxplvr1v5&dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no node system for objects in Blender currently, only geometry. You can only do that with drivers and/or Python.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this information, I note as validate for now (and hope it'll be possible in the futur, hadn't chance to go to blender-conf this year, i'll go to their blender.chat to ask about it)

Comment: I don't really think scene level nodes for cameras will be a thing any time soon. Not a lot of people need this sort of functionality and the ones who do already have Python for it. It's hard to imagine how this could work and what it could be used for... I think there are a lot of things considered higher priority then nodes for managing scene objects. This is however just an opinion. Who knows...

Comment: Indeed, just an opinion, mine is quite the opposite of yours, having geometry node only acting as a mograph to make cool thing only to get close to what c4d community does isn't in my opinion an objective for a real general purpose 3D toolsets that is blender. Getting closer to houdini and having geometry node work on object as well would help do anything wanted and could help avoid the giant single nodetree spaggethi monster by separating block of logic into more straightforward general purpose node that work outside geometry.

Comment: Also i wanted to mention, even with chat-gpt-4 and ~5year (non-proactive) of python scripting, solving quaternions is still hard to just reproduce the mirror modifier in python. I just dropped down the idea and didn't do what I wanted to do due to lack of tool and money to pay freelancer to do for me.

Comment: You could ask a question about Python and mirroring a camera with it here. Python API questions are OK on BSE. If it's specific and well formed, I think it will get answered in no time. It would be helpful to provide more context though and explain exact functionality you need.

Comment: Thank you, I know I could ask here for python help, but I don't really wish to make waste time for asking python snippet for having a mirror modifier for camera. Python snippets are often not updated in each stackoverflow questions, doesn't integrate well on specific workflow (ex : custom parenting, constraints) and are hard to maintain on each computer I go (for example setting-up computers ~20 students). What I would ask would rather be a c++ code for geometry-node implementation, but I doubt competent person would spend time for free here.